# Python append_sum(lst)

Tags: python, append

**The request is**

"Write a function named append_sum that has one parameter named lst.

The function should add the last two elements of lst together and append the result to lst. It should do this process three times and then return lst.

For example, if lst started as [1, 1, 2], the final result should be [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]."

**My code is:**

```
def append_sum(lst):

    first = lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])

    second = first.append(first[-1] + first[-2])

    third = second.append(second[-1] + second[-2])

    return third

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

**Then here is the err:**
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File 'script.py', line 9, in 
    print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
    File 'script.py', line 4, in append_sum
    second = first.append(first[-1] + first[-2])
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
    'append'

Where am I wrong and why? Thank you!

Comment: The code you've posted isn't valid syntactically. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: The `append` method of `lst` modifies it in place, and returns `None`. Just do `lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])` as many times as you need.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Understand now, thank you!

Comment: @jonrsharpe modified, thanks!

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/MeagerUprightDebugger.  Bonus points if you use a loop instead of 3 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful.

```
number = 3 #number of times you want to add last two number
lst = [1,2,3]
def append_sum(lst, number):
    i = 0;
    while i<number:
        lst.append(lst[-1]+lst[-2])
        i = i + 1
    return lst
print(append_sum(lst,number))
```

Comment: variable number gives the number of times while loop iterates (in this case 3), so in the first iteration the operation lst.append(2+3) will takes place. Now the lst becomes = [1,2,3,5] so for the nest iteration operation lst.append(3+5) will takes place and as the result lst will become [1,2,3,5,8] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 def append_sum(lst, N):
        for i in range(N):
            lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
        return lst

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2],3))
```